# sifr3 not displaying at all in safari 4 for pc and safari 4 for mac

Tags: safari, sifr

I am using sifr3 in a rather ambitious manner - all text on the page is converted. I know this is not ideal but I don't think this explains the issue I am experiencing.
It's working fine in IE 8 and Firefox 3.0.1. However, there's nothing to be seen on Safari for Mac or PC.

Here's the page I'm working on: http://www.merlyncricket.com/home/

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here: it had very little to do with sifr itself... The problem arose due to a javascript for bookmarking purposes. I don't quite understand the ins and outs but have simply removed the script for the bookmarking (it queried the browser and presented a different solution for each browser type) - and all works beautifully.

Sorry to bore you.

M